# how to attach a header in axios.all()

Tags: javascript, axios, http-headers

Is there any way to attach a header in axios.all method or do we have to attach the header to each request individually.

```js
axios.all([
    axios.delete('http://localhost:5000/requests/'+{id}),
    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/records/'+{id, response}),
],{
    headers: {Authorization: localStorage.getItem('auth-token')}
}).then(res => console.log(res.data))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an `axios` instance and use the same instance for all requests (recommended)

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Sample:

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  headers: {
     Authorization: localStorage.getItem('auth-token')
  }
});

axios.all([
  axiosInstance.delete("http://localhost:5000/requests/" + {id}),
  axiosInstance.post("http://localhost:5000/records/" + {id, response})
  ]).then((res) => {
    console.log("Response: ", res);
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error); 
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the default headers for all the requests as given

```js
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token;
```

After setting this, All subsequent network calls will carry the `Authorization` header by default. This workaround will help you to provide application global header like `Authorization` header. You can create separate Axios instance as

```
const axiosInstance axios.create({
  headers: {Authorization: token}
});
```

You can choose one of the workarounds.

Comment: This will work in Axios everywhere, you just need to configure it from right place. :)

Comment: Q2 . can you kindly tell me any config file in react where i can set this property (axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token), so that i don't have to import this in every file or manually type it THANKS.......

Comment: Do you have the independent API file which is being used for all the API calls? If yes, you can import Axios there and configure it there, Here is the good article to start with https://designrevision.com/react-axios/#integrating-and-configuring-axios-in-your-react-project